# driver for XP-6005 printer

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

Can anyone tell me Where can I get a printer driver for EPSOn XP-6005? 
Have tried Epson and a search without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the driver that Epson release
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=69276&DSCCHK=fbc915ed48294804d44c46bfcb92136c9bb78bd0

if you have 64bit Ubuntu, it comes down as epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2_1.0.11-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb so installs as a debian package: are you happy to do that? It was released Jan 2018

This is the link for the Epson portal for linux http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX so you can see where I started